# Custom ModelMetadataProvider is a singleton but depends on a request-scoped service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ioc-container

In my ASP.NET MVC project, I have a custom ModelMetadataProvider that requires a service `PropertyAccess`. I'm currently using constructor injection and an IOC container (Ninject) to do the dirty work. The problem is that `PropertyAccess` is request scoped, while my ModelMetadataProvider is only created once (at application start up). This results in the `PropertyAccess` service being out of date/incorrect.

In case it matters, here is how I'm setting up my ModelMetadataProvider in my Global.asax:

```
private void RegisterModelMetadataProvider()
{
    var metadataProvider = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<CustomModelMetadataProvider>();
    ModelMetadataProviders.Current = metadataProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I'm answering my own question (Q&A style), but I'm not convinced this is an ideal solution. Please comment or leave an alternative answer if you have a better way (such as one that only needs configuration).]

Instead of passing `PropertyAccess` directly into the singleton class, pass in a `PropertyAccessLocator`, which can be used to get the `PropertyAccess` for the current request as needed.

**Here is the PropertyAccessLocator**

```
public class PropertyAccessLocator
{
    public PropertyAccess Get()
    {
        return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<PropertyAccess>();
    }
}
```

**Here is an example ModelMetadataProvider**

```
public class CustomModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    private readonly PropertyAccessLocator _propertyAccessLocator;

    public CustomModelMetadataProvider(
        PropertyAccessLocator propertyAccessLocator)
    {
        _propertyAccessLocator = propertyAccessLocator;
        // required because PropertyAccess is request scoped
        // while this class is a singleton 
    }

    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(
        IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes,
        Type containerType,
        Func<object> modelAccessor,
        Type modelType,
        string propertyName)
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(
            attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
        var propertyAccess = _propertyAccessLocator.Get();
        // todo use propertyAccess to do something with the metadata...
        return metadata;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this dirty solution as it is the only thing that worked!